# jQuery mobile: new content on internal page transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to write a simple app that has several internal pages. From `#page2` I want to return to `#page1` AND reload it so that content generated by javascript will refresh.

```
<body>
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //Javascript spits out something new every time
    </script>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <a id="page1button" href="page1" data-role="button">go to page1</a>
</div>
</body>
```

The only way I can make this work is by adding `rel="external"` to `#page1button`. The content refreshes BUT there is an abrupt page reload that isn't sexy. Is there a way to achieve the same results, but still use jqm's transitions?

I know this is a popular question and I've done a lot of research, including [the jqm documentation on changing pages](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html), but nothing I've tried seems to work. `$.mobile.changePage()` appears to have an option: `reloadPage:true` which claims to do exactly what I need, but it doesn't work. I've even tried `$.mobile.loadPage()` BEFORE `.changePage()` and still no luck. Help!

#### UPDATE:

I'm pretty sure this isn't a caching issue because here's what my page element looks like and it STILL shows the same *$#%&ing thing every time I return to the page:

```
<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-cache="never" data-dom-cache="false"> ...
```

I'm thinking that the javascript block only gets called once when the html page loads, rather than each time I return to that div using jqm. Maybe the way to solve this is by figuring out a way to force that block of code to run again. Any ideas?

#### UPDATE:

Good news: I found the page which speaks to this EXACT issue: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Bad news: What it claims will work...

`$( document ).delegate("#page1", "pageinit", function() {
  alert('RE-RUN JAVASCRIPT');
});`

...DOESN'T!! I placed this function in the head of my html file and it only runs once.

#### UPDATE:

Still struggling with this. I put some code up here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28286159/index.html

To keep things simple, I just did two pages with one of them containing a `<script>` that prints out: `document.write(Math.random());`

You you'll see that the number doesn't change.

Comment: what do you want? you want to have page transition styles while navigating from one page to another?

Comment: Um. Yes. I think (if I understand your question correctly). I already get nice page transitions between different divs with `data-role="page"` but I loose them when I add the attribute `rel="external"`. When I remove this attribute, I see the same content on #page1 every time I go there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. Your #predict page is still in the dom since its all one page. So yes your math.random code is only executing once. Just bind the random number to a click of the "tell me" button and update #prediction with a new random number generated by the click.

```
<script>
    $(function(){   
        $('#tellme').click(function(){       
            randomNumber = Math.random();
            $('#prediction').html(randomNumber);
            $.mobile.changePage('#predict', {transition:'pop'});
        });
    }); 
</script>
<section id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 class="">HOME</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="iknow">Here's a random number...</div>

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="tellme">TELL ME!</a>

    </div><!-- /content -->
</section><!--#home-->
<section id="predict" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 class="">PREDICT</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

        <div id="prediction"></div>

        <a id="tryagain" href="#home" data-role="button" data-transition="pop">Try again.</a>

     </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #predict -->
```

Comment: This is working! I notice there's no `href` attribute on the `#tellme` button. Is that significant? I wonder if it will still work if I leave the `href` on the button and do `event.preventDefault(); ` then add the `.changePage... ` in the script

Comment: Also, I'm curious to know what is confusing about what I'm doing. Am I doing something strange?

Comment: I didn't include the href because I am using that button to trigger your random number then using $.mobile.changePage().

Comment: You may have a good reason to do it that way. I don't know the bigger picture. I said it was confusing because it all could be done with one page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a page transition to work then you need to prefetch the external page.

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

The documentation goes on to say this exactly:

> **DOM size management**
>
> For animated page transitions to work, the pages
>   you're transitioning from and to both need to be in the DOM. However,
>   keeping old pages in the DOM quickly fills the browser's memory, and
>   can cause some mobile browsers to slow down or even crash.

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: This looks really promising, but I can't get this links to work with `data-prefetch` unless I also add `rel="external"` and this seems to prevent the ajax-y transitions from happening. Also, in order to simplify things, I created separate html files instead of using divs/sections with `data-role="page"`. Not sure if this matters or not.

Comment: It certainly seems like it should work. Are your pages in separate HTML files? I'm confused because I can't even get the link to work at all between different html files if I don't add `rel="external"`. So I must be doing something different.

Comment: Yes they are. You know, I seem to recall that `<script>` blocks from ajax loaded jqm pages don't work well unless they are in the `<div data-role="content">` block.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense, but sadly my `<script>` is inside a `data-role="content"` block. I found the exact page in the jqm docs that talks about that:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

But what it says there isn't working for me (see my edit above). It's frustrating!

Do you think it matters whether I do a multi-page format on one html file, or separate html files? I've experimented with both, but it would be nice to at least rule out that variable.

Comment: For testing issues like this I believe it will be easier to keep them as you desire them when you are finished, just so you didn't get a half solution working that breaks down when you refactor. Do you have sample pages somewhere public?

Comment: That's good advice. I don't have publicly visible code at the moment because the pages in question are part of a PhoneGap mobile app project. It would take some work to extract the relevant code into a freestanding form. I tried jsfiddle and it didn't really work. Is your code visible anywhere?

Comment: I take it back... through the magic that is dropbox I have posted some code: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28286159/index.html

To keep things simple, I just did two pages with one of them containing a `<script>` that prints out: `document.write(Math.random());`

You you'll see that the number doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

In this case both "home" and "predict" pages will load into the DOM initially.

In order to keep the size of the browser’s DOM to a minimum, jQuery Mobile
automatically removes any dynamically-loaded mobile page from the DOM once
it’s been transitioned out of view. **This only applies to mobile pages loaded
dynamically via Ajax; pages already in the markup of a multi-page document aren’t
removed.**

So your predict page will be available in the DOM all the time. In order to update that content on the page, update the content and call the appropriate refresh method, so that jquery mobile will enhance the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

use **`pageshow`** (or better, **`pagebeforeshow`**) instead of `pageinit`.

`pageinit` is only called once to avoid unnecessary re-apply jQuery mobile UI. While `pageshow` and `pagebeforeshow` is called everytime the page is shown, and that is what you need to mimic the page refresh in your case.

Further reading here:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

and here is the modify of your index for quick visual:
http://jsfiddle.net/tSYUK/